# React Hook Forms control undefined value in form after failed submit

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-select

I'm using React Hook Form with React Select, but to style the React Select I made a wrapper component.
And what happens is that everything work fine until the form submits and the value of **item_presupuestario** is lost within the form, but the value in the control render is still there, the item is still selected.
I don't understand why the value in the form is undefined while the value is in the control render is there.

React Select wrapper component

```
import { RefCallBack } from "react-hook-form";
import Select, { Props as SelectProps } from "react-select";

export const CustomSelect = <T,>({
  isInvalid = true,
  selectRef,
  ...props
}: CustomSelectProps<T>) => (
  <Select
    noOptionsMessage={() => "No se encontraron resultados"}
    {...props}
    ref={selectRef}
    unstyled
    classNames={{
      ...
    }}
    styles={{
      ...
    }}
  />
);

interface CustomSelectProps<T> extends SelectProps<T, any, any> {
  isInvalid?: boolean;
  selectRef: RefCallBack;
}
```

React Hook Form Controller

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="item_presupuestario"
  rules={{ required: "Campo obligatorio" }}
  disabled={isSaving}
  render={({ field: { ref, disabled, name, onBlur, onChange, value } }) => (
    <>
      <CustomSelect<{ value: string; label: string }>
        selectRef={ref}
    isDisabled={disabled}
    name={name}
    onBlur={onBlur}
    onChange={onChange}
    value={value}
    defaultValue={value}
    isClearable
    placeholder="Seleccionar el Item presupuestario"
    options={
      itemsPresupuestarios.map((itemPresupuestario) => ({
            value: itemPresupuestario.codigo,
        label: `${itemPresupuestario.nombre} (${itemPresupuestario.codigo})`,
      })) ?? []
    }
    isInvalid={errors ? true : false}
      />
      {errors && (
        <small className="text-danger float-end">{errors.message}</small>
      )}
    </>
  )}
/>
```

Form values before submit (with React Hook Form Watch())

```
{
    ...
    "item_presupuestario": {
        "value": "2209002",
        "label": "ARRIENDO DE EDIFICIOS (2209002)"
    },
    ...
}
```

Form values after submit (with React Hook Form Watch())

```
{
    ...
    "item_presupuestario": undefined,
    ...
}
```

Submit handler

```
  const {
    mutate: mutateCrear,
    isLoading: isLoading,
  } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: crearSolicitud,
    onSuccess: ({ data }): void => {
      if (data.numero_solicitud && data.periodo) {
        alertaToast({
          titulo: "Solicitud creada",
          posicion: "center",
        });
        handleOnModalClose({ recargar: true });
      } else
        alertaError({
          titulo: "Ocurrió un error inesperado al intentar crear la solicitud",
        });
    },
  });

  const handleOnSubmit: SubmitHandler<
    FormCrear
  > = async (data): Promise<void> => {
    mutateCrear({
      ...
      codigo_item_presupuestario: data.item_presupuestario.value,
    });
  };
```

useForm

```
const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    watch,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
} = useForm<FormCrear>({
    mode: "all",
});
```

I managed to make it work with a useEffect() that sets the value in the form with the one in the control.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (
    !watch("item_presupuestario") &&
    control._fields.item_presupuestario?._f.value
  )
    setValue(
      "item_presupuestario",
      control._fields.item_presupuestario?._f.value
    );
}, [watch("item_presupuestario")]);
```

But I don't think I should have to do this. Is this ok? or did I do something wrong with the wrapper component?

**Solution:**

It was the `disabled={isSaving}` in the Controller component, when it turns to false the value becomes undefined.

The isSaving was just changing between true and false depending on whether the post had resolved.

```
<Controller
      control={control}
      name="item_presupuestario"
      rules={{ required: "Campo obligatorio" }}
      // disabled={isSaving}
      render={({ field: { ref, disabled, name, onBlur, onChange, value } }) => (
        <>
          <CustomSelect<{ value: string; label: string }>
            selectRef={ref}
            isDisabled={isSaving}
            name={name}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            isClearable
            placeholder="Seleccionar el Item presupuestario"
            options={
              [
                { value: "111", label: "Option 1" },
                { value: "222", label: "Option 2" },
              ]
            }
            isInvalid={errors ? true : false}
          />
          {errors && (
            <small className="text-danger float-end">{errors.message}</small>
          )}
        </>
      )}
    />
```

Removing the disabled on the controller and setting it directly on the select fixed the issue.

Comment: Are the `options` from an API (`itemsPresupuestarios`)? If so, do they get refreshed on submit? Or are they defined as a literal inside the component definition, or elsewhere? Would help to show this as your issue is possibly because of the options being recreated which would cause them to not be referentially the same as the value anymore.

Comment: The options do come from an API but it only gets called once. Still changed the options to `options={[{ value: "111", label: "Option 1" },{ value: "222", label: "Option 2" }]}` and still got the same problem

Comment: If you defined `options={[{ value: "111", label: "Option 1" },{ value: "222", label: "Option 2" }]}` in component render the problem would persist. Try to define it *outside* of the whole component definition as a static constant at the root of the file (so its stable between rerenders) to rule it out completely.

Comment: Also, may or may not be related, but you should remove `defaultValue={value}` as that is for uncontrolled mode. You already control this by `value`. And make sure that this field has a *valid* value set in `defaultValues`. That will likely also mean not rendering the control until the options are ready. This is important otherwise you open up the possibility of the control switching between controlled and uncontrolled modes which leads to ambiguous behaviour.

Comment: Moved the `options={[{ value: "111", label: "Option 1" },{ value: "222", label: "Option 2" }]}` outside of the component function definition and removed the `defaultValues`. The issue persists.

Comment: Hmm. Its hard to debug further without seeing a minimal example on codesandbox or otherwise. If you can set that up, will be happy to identify it.

Comment: I was trying to set up a codesandbox and stumbled on the cause of the problem, edited the question to add the solution. Thanks for the help.